# Header in email not working

Tags: php, email

I am using the following script below.  The email gets sent correctly except the html tags don't work.  What is wrong here?

```
  function spamcheck($field)
  {
 //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
 //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
 $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

 //filter_var() validates the e-mail
 //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
 if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
  return TRUE;
  }
 else
  {
  return FALSE;
   }
   }

 if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
 {//if "email" is filled out, proceed

  //check if the email address is invalid
    $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['email']);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
   {
   echo "Invalid input";
    }
   else
   {//send email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
      $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
      $subject = "My Email";
     $message = "<html><body>";
     $message .= "<h1>Hello</h1>";
      $message .= "Let us know if you have any questions.";
      $message .= "</body></html>";
      mail("$email", "Subject: $subject",
$message, "From: $usermail", "$headers" );
    echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
    }
    }
   else
   {
  //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  echo "<form method='post' action='mailform.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br />
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' /><br />
   Message:<br />
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br />
  <input type='submit' />
  </form>";
   }
```

Comment: Don't build your own mime messages. [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) to do it for you.

Comment: @Marc B. That's certainly not the problem here.

Comment: @Golez: which is why it's a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers should be the fourth parameter. Now you pass the 'FROM' header there, and pass the MIME headers as the fifth. That's why the MIME header is not used as a header. Combine the headers in the fourth parameter like so:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn"; 
$headers  .= "From: $usermail\r\n"; 

// now lets send the email. 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

(gratefully borrowed from http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=416467)

Comment: thanks.  this works but because of $headers  .= "From: $from\r\n"; the email that it is being sent from doesn't show.  instead i see www-data..

Comment: Sure. I just copied the code from the link I gave. You should use your own `$usermail` variable instead of `$from`. I now modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PHP's [`mail`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. You are calling it as such:

```
mail("$email", "Subject: $subject", $message, "From: $usermail", "$headers" );
```

The `"From: $usermail"` is being interpreted as the `additional_headers`, and your headers are being interpreted as `additional_parameters`. Thus, your custom headers are not being set.